# Lambda Expression not giving desired result

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, lambda

I have sql query as :-

```
SELECT CreatedOn,* FROM [dbo].[ClientConfigurationVersion] --order by CreatedOn
WHERE CONVERT(date,CreatedOn)>=CONVERT(date,'2019-03-15')
and CONVERT(date,CreatedOn)<=CONVERT(date,'2019-03-20')
```

This is giving me below 2 records :-

[image]

I want to fetch this result through Lambda Expression.
I written it as :-

```
var clientConfigurationVersion= context.ClientConfigurationVersions.Where(x => (x.CreatedOn >= _startDate) && (x.CreatedOn <= _endDate) );
```

I passed same dates , but it gives me only one record i.e. first record which we can see in Sql Result window.

What is wrong in my Lambda Expression ?

Comment: `CONVERT(date, ...)` only applies to the date part and omits the time. You don't do the same in C#.

Comment: Did you make sure `_startDate` time is set to `00:00` and `_endDate` time is set to `23:59`?

Comment: @haim770 This actually worked.. Thanks a lot